Lombok getters not generated with maven
With the below dependency and plugins specified for Lombok and maven-compiler-plugin, it does't generate the Lombok getters and setters for @Getter and @Setter. I'm facing the problem both in Intellij IDE and in command line mvn. As per all available answers on this very often repeated question, the below settings should work but it doesn't for me. Any help is much appreciated.
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>1.18.32</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>      
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>17</source>
          <target>17</target>
          <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
              <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
              <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
              <version>1.18.32</version>
            </path>
          </annotationProcessorPaths>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

